# Custom caption for tables in `beamer`

Tags: tables, beamer, captions, naming

I’m using the `caption` package, to name tables in `beamer`. `\caption{Name}` automatically provides **Table: Name** output. I would like to change the word “Table” to a custom caption, but also to be able to have a different caption for different tables. E.g.:

```
\documentclass[pdf,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
\usepackage{caption}
\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \caption{Name 1.}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
   &  \\ \hline
   &  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \caption{Name 2.}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  &  \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Above the first table gets a caption “Table: Name 1.” and the second “Table: Name 2.”. I want to be able to call the first one “Random Caption: Name 1.”, and second “Different Random Caption: Name 2.”. Can I change this caption for different tables independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) for this as you can just redefine `\tablename` to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Random Caption}
    \caption{Name 1.}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Different Random Caption}
    \caption{Name 2.}
  \end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The redefinition is localized to the `table` environment, like with all scoping within the `\begin` ... `\end` group.